# Commands in dockerfile to run spring boot application deployed on jboss server

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jboss

I am new in docker. I have a springboot application which is running on jboss-eap-7.2. Usually when I want to run the application, first I have to run command **mvn clean package** in cmd and then after build success, I run ***standalone.bat -c standalone_wingsure.xml***, and it works fine. 
I want to run this application in docker container. So I created a *DockerFile*, which include this code.

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1.war wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1.war
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-war", "wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1.war"]
```

This springboot application has mysql database connection. So I created docker container for mysql image. Here is my **appliaction.properties** file .

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-standalone:3306/crop_insurance
spring.datasource.username=chronito
spring.datasource.password=mysql
```

My pom.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.wingsure</groupId>
<artifactId>wingsure_crop_insurance</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>wingsure_crop_insurance</name>
<description>Crop Insurance</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>3.1.0</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> -->


    <dependency>
         <groupId>botlibre-ai</groupId>
         <artifactId>botlibre-ai</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\botlibre-ai.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>27.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${env.JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/deployments/</outputDirectory>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.wingsure.WingsureCropInsuranceApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After ***mvn clean install*** the war file is generated in ***/target folder***.
Then I build the image for the application by running command `D:\chronito\checkout\wingsure_crop_insurance\wingsure_crop_insurance>docker build . -t wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1`

After building image I run the image in container by linking with mysql container and it successfully runs the container without any error.

```
D:\chronito\checkout\wingsure_crop_insurance\wingsure_crop_insurance>docker run -p 8080:8080 --name wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1 --link mysql-standalone:mysql -d wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1
7db57549b4c94ee0546275b962482a95b215f7aaf576be3d82340ec1934f117f
```

But when I see the logs I get the error like this -

```
D:\chronito\checkout\wingsure_crop_insurance\wingsure_crop_insurance>docker logs wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1
Unrecognized option: -war
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

After EbrahimPasbani's solution the previous error is gone, but it did not startup the springboot application. After I run the docker command

```
D:\chronito\checkout\wingsure_crop_insurance\wingsure_crop_insurance>docker run -p 8080:8080 --name wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1 --link mysql-standalone:mysql -d wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1
7b3836cb4da2d6ab1c1a55b1fa2c3ac500c99372313388cdeb54f24249e073bd
```

it successfully run the container and shows the logs as

```
=========================================================================

12:34:52,374 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.6.Final-redhat-00001

I> No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
Jolokia: Agent started with URL https://172.17.0.3:8778/jolokia/

12:34:53,501 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.5.Final-redhat-00001

12:34:53,520 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final-redhat-1
```

The main class is -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
FileStorageProperties.class
})
public class WingsureCropInsuranceApplication extends 
SpringBootServletInitializer{
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
application)
{
    return application.sources(WingsureCropInsuranceApplication.class);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WingsureCropInsuranceApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: The error itself clearly says that the war option is not recognized as there is no such option as war. You can generate a jar packaging and run using jar option. If you are bound to a war packaging, you can see the link below https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2018/08/06/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-war-in-wildfly-jboss/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java`  command does not have `-war` option.
If you want to use jboss then you need to deploy your war to jboss in docker.
So the docker file should be from jboss like below:

```
#start from eap72-openshift
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-eap-7/eap72-openshift

# Copy war to deployments folder
COPY target/wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1.war $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/

# User root to modify war owners
USER root

# Modify owners war
RUN chown jboss:jboss $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/wingsure_crop_insurance-0.0.1.war

# Important, use jboss user to run image
USER jboss
```

Comment: Thank you @EbrahimPasbani, it solved the error and give me something useful, but it not startup the springboot application.

Comment: @KaustabhNag No problem. Have you deployed on jboss without docker successfully?

Comment: yes I can deploy the application on jboss without docker.

Comment: @KaustabhNag Did you exclude tomcat in pom file?

Comment: yeah I did. You can check into my pom.xml file given on my question.

Comment: @KaustabhNag First) How do you find out your application doesn't setup? Second) Can you show your SpringBootApplication class containing `main` method?

Comment: 1) When hitting any of the rest url it gives 404 not found. 2) the main class I edited on my questions.

Comment: @KaustabhNag Where is the class?

Comment: @KaustabhNag Ok I saw that. As far as I see, there is no problem. It doesn't come to my mind anything else.

Comment: Okay thanks anyways.. Can u help me on one last thing? What should be the command to run ***standalone.bat -c standalone_wingsure.xml***, which is located on D:\jboss-eap-7.2\standalone\configuration

Comment: @KaustabhNag You're welcome. Please take a look at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/using_the_red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform_docker_image/index